# What is the PageElement type?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In this code, I have asserted that the `event` object must be an instance of the [`Tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#bs4.Tag) class:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
from requests import get

html = open("ticketbox.html", "r") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

event = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "table-cell event-title"})
try:
    assert isinstance(event, Tag) 
    event_url = event.contents[1]['href']

except:
    pass
```

Pylance tells me that the type of the [`contents` attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) is `list[PageElement]`, and thus there is no [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=getitem#object.__getitem__) method here. However it still works fine.

What is this type? And how can it still work without this method?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**:

`pageElement` is not a list. It's an `object`. See the [official doc](https://pydocbrowser.github.io/beautifulsoup4/latest/bs4.element.PageElement.html). You asked why it still works. It works because `contents` *is* a list. `Pylance` correctly identifies the `pageElement` as an `object` that *does not implement* the `__getitem__()` dunder. `contents` is a `list` that holds `pageElement` objects. That's it.

The `bs4` [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) says that `contents` is a `list`.

And the python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=getitem#object.__getitem__) says that the `__getitem__` dunder is

> For sequence types, the accepted keys should be integers and slice objects.

And if you go and checkout what a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) in Pyton is then you'll learn that it's

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer indices via the **getitem**() special method and defines a **len**() method that returns the length of the sequence.

One example of an iterable that supports the `__getitem()__` is [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

That is why *it still works fine*.

However, I can't reproduce your example, as you do not provide the `HTML` source code, but my guess is that `Pylance` might not be entirely correct about the true nature of `contents`.

Comment: The `__getitem__()` is applied to a `PageElement` object, not the list of it (`event.contents[1]['href']`), so it's important to discuss about the nature of `PageElement` object first. Also, what is the difference between a dunder and a non-dunder (e.g. `__getitem__()` vs `getitem()`)?

Comment: No, the `__getitem()__` is applied to the list that holds `PageElement`. The `bs4` docs are clear about it. `contents` is a *list*. The `__getitem__()` dunder is a built-in method in Python that allows instances of a class to use the `[]` operator to access elements of a collection, while `getitem()` is a user-defined method that can be used to access elements of a collection.

Comment: Yes, `contents` is a list, but isn't the syntax `contents[1]` tell us that it's an element of a list, which is not a list? Or do you mean that PageElement itself is a list?

Comment: No, `pageElement` is *not* a `list`. It's an *object*. See the [official doc](https://pydocbrowser.github.io/beautifulsoup4/latest/bs4.element.PageElement.html). You asked why it still works. It works because `contents` *is* a `list`. Pylance correctly identifies the `pageElement` as an object that *does not* implement the `__getitem__()` dunder. `contents` is a `list` that holds `pageElement` objects. That's it.

Comment: I still don't get it. Yes, `contents` is a list, but the code is not `contents.__getitem__()`. It's  `contents[1].__getitem__()`. Since `contents[1]` is not a list, why can `__getitem__()` still be able to be applied to it?

Comment: Look, don't trust blindly the type checker. The `__getitem__()` method is a special method in Python that allows an object to use the indexing syntax (e.g., `contents[1]`) like a list or dictionary. The error message you are seeing from Pylance seems to suggest that the type checker is not recognizing that `contents` is a list, but this is likely a false positive from the type checker.